# Azure DNS not working (after 48 hours and chatting with DNS provider)

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a site hosted at mysite.azurewebsites.net.

I have a domain from hover.com - mysite.com - which I've configured with CNAME records per the inline instructions AND msdn documentation.

I've spoken to hover and verified on whatsmydns.com that the cname records have propagated - which they have.

Yet when I type mysite.com or www.mysite.com (I have one CNAME for each) into the azure custom domain input - it doesn't resolve, even after 24 hours of the entry being edited on hover's end (They have a 1 hour TT).  I get the generic "The DNS record could not be located" error.

Images:

[image]
[image]

If I check whatsmydns for www.mysite.com, I see all dns records pointing to mysite.azurewebsites.net.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem - I just had to wait.  It took a little over 48 hours for Azure to resolve the CNAME entries from hover.  It's all set now though :)